# Can run rake but not push to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have a remote on heroku called `staging`. I can

```
heroku run rake db:version --remote staging
```

but if I try `git push staging master`
I receive the error message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

However I can push to github e.g. `git push origin master`

What is the easiest way to fix this?

Comment: Have You added your local machine `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to heroku dshboard `Manage Account > ssh keys` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add your system public key to heroku ssh keys. You can copy `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` content and paste while adding ssh keys from `Manage account > SSH keys > Edit`.

Comment: Thanks this worked, on my Mac OSX, the key was at ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub